# When the "Body" field is required, how can I force users to input, say, at least 400 characters?

Tags: 7, entities

For example, this site (Drupal Answers) has this feature-- if you input too little text in the text box, the interface prompts you to write more.  Is there a module to do this?  I tried various searches but I haven't been able to find anything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to just use the [Field validation](http://drupal.org/project/field_validation) module to set a minimum length on the body field.

> This module adds an extra tab to each field instance, allowing you to
>   specify validation rules for your field instances.
>
> By using the hooks provided by this module, you can also define your
>   own validation rules in your own modules.

Answer (score 2):

If you are comfortable with code, the basic approach is to [hook_form_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) the [node_form](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.pages.inc/function/node_form/7) and add an additional [#validate](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#validate) to the field.  Just note that allowing markup in the field will count towards charaters.  You may want to base your count off of what [strip_tags](http://php.net/strip_tags) returns, rather than the actual field value.

Answer (score 2):

In addition you could implement an 'n characters to go' counter for minimum length (a la stackoverflow) with javascript/jquery which counts before submission.