# How can I track statistics on how often a hook/error message is triggered?

Tags: hooks, nodes

I am using the [Privatemsg](http://drupal.org/project/privatemsg) module in Drupal 7.  I have a hook in a custom module that is triggered when users write a message that is too short.  I set this up using the instructions [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/33060/how-can-i-enforce-a-minimum-length-for-private-messages/33064#33064).

Basically, it looks like this:

```
function mymodule_privatemsg_message_validate($message) {
  $uid = $vars['message']->author->uid;

  //if root or help user, message should always go through regardless of length
  if ($uid !== '1') {
    if ($uid !== '3') {

      if (empty($message->thread_id) && strlen($message->body) < 200 ) {
    form_set_error('[body][value]', t('My custom message.'));
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I recently noticed there are not so many messages being sent on my site.  I would like to know if it is because they are being blocked by this hook.  How can I track how many times it is triggered (and even better if I can know which logged-in users are getting the error message)?

Comment: As side note, you are using `$vars`, but that variable has not been initialized from the function, nor is a function's parameter.

Comment: @kiamlaluno Sorry, I don't understand your comment.  Could you please clarify here? http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/50144/whats-wrong-with-the-way-i-use-variables-in-my-function

Comment: I answered, and I also said what else is wrong in your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you'll get 'statistics' as such without some coding yourself, I've never seen a module that does that sort of thing (but hey it's Drupal so there probably is one somewhere).

Failing that I think your best bet would be to use the the `watchdog()` function, combined with enabling the dblog module on your site. You can use it like so:

```
if (empty($message->thread_id) && strlen($message->body) < 200 ) {
  form_set_error('[body][value]', t('My custom message.'));

  global $user;
  watchdog('mymodule', 'My custom message for user @username', array('@username' => $user->name));
}
```

Every time that `if` statement is entered you'll get a message on the 'Recent log messages' page, where you can even filter by entries for your own module, giving you a basic idea of what's happening, when, and for whom.

Comment: Is it possible to e-mail myself the watchdog message?  Or to send an e-mail with the same message?  I don't need an elaborate solution; just some notifications I can't miss (e-mails) would suffice.

Comment: @Patrick I don't think there's anything built in but the [Logging and Alerts module](http://drupal.org/project/logging_alerts) should do the trick; one of its features is _Allows routing of watchdog messages to various email addresses, based on their severity levels._