# What's wrong with the way I use variables in my function?

Tags: privatemsg

I have a function that looks like this:

```
function mymodule_privatemsg_message_validate($message) {
  $uid = $vars['message']->author->uid;

  //if root or help user, message should always go through regardless of length
  if ($uid !== '1') {
    if ($uid !== '3') {

      if (empty($message->thread_id) && strlen($message->body) < 200 ) {
    form_set_error('[body][value]', t('My custom message.'));
      }
    }
  }
}
```

However, I received [a comment](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/49995/how-can-i-track-statistics-on-how-often-a-hook-error-message-is-triggered/50005#comment51867_50005) that "As side note, you are using $vars, but that variable has not been initialized from the function, nor is a function's parameter."  I don't understand what this means or what I'm doing wrong.  Could someone explain this to me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The parameters given to [hook_privatemsg_message_validate()](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!privatemsg!privatemsg.api.php/function/hook_privatemsg_message_validate/7) are `$message`, and `$form` which has a default value of `FALSE`.
`$vars` is not a parameter passed to the function, nor is a local variable defined from the function. As consequence of this, the value of `$vars` is `NULL`. When you try accessing `$vars['message']->author->uid`, PHP would give you two warnings:

- Undefined variable: vars
- Trying to get property of non-object

The first warning is because the variable is not defined from the function. If your code would have assigned a value to `$vars` the warning would not appear. It would also work if `$vars` is defined as global (with `global $vars;`), and it was already initialized from another function.
The second warning is because every PHP variable that is not define get an automatic value that is `NULL`. `$vars` is `NULL`, and so is `$vars['message']`, and `NULL` is not an object.

The result is that `$uid` is set to `NULL` too.

The following code is also wrong.

```
  if ($uid !== '1') {
    if ($uid !== '3') {
      if (empty($message->thread_id) && strlen($message->body) < 200 ) {
        form_set_error('[body][value]', t('My custom message.'));
      }
    }
  }
```

With `$uid !== '1'` you are saying to PHP to check if `$uid` is a string with a value that is different from `'1'`. If `$uid` is set to 1 (the integer), the following code would print `"different"`, not `"equal"`.

```
$uid = 1;

if ($uid !== '1') {
  print "different";
else {
  print "equal";
}
```

Differently, the following code prints `"equal"`.

```
$uid = 1;

if ($uid != '1') {
  print "different";
else {
  print "equal";
}
```

Also the following code will print `"equal"`. (To the reader, the task to understand why. `;)`)

```
$uid = '1a';

if ($uid != 1) {
  print "different";
else {
  print "equal";
}
```

What you meant to write is the following code, as the user ID for a user object is an integer, not a string.

```
function mymodule_privatemsg_message_validate($message) {
  $uid = $message->author->uid;

  //if root or help user, message should always go through regardless of length
  if ($uid != 1 && $uid != 3) {
    if (empty($message->thread_id) && strlen($message->body) < 200 ) {
      form_set_error('[body][value]', t('My custom message.'));
    }
  }
}
```

I am not sure if `$message->author` is a property defined for `$message`, but I guess that is what you really need.

As side note, I would rather avoid checking the user ID for a user object, and take any action basing on that value. In Drupal, it is better to check if the user has a permission, using code similar to the following one.

```
if (user_access('permission to check', $account)) {
  // The user has the permission.
}
```

`$account` is an user object.

If you have just a user ID, then you can use the following code.

```
$account = user_load($uid);
if ($account && user_access('permission to check', $account)) {
  // The user has the permission.
}
```

The reason for checking the permission instead of user IDs is maintainability of the code. Imagine what happens if you have 100 users, and just 50 of them should see that error message: You should check the value of `$uid` is not the user ID for those users that should not see the error message. If they have not consecutive values (as it happened in your case, where the user IDs were 1 and 3), you should check each value singularly.

As side note, `user_access()` always return `TRUE` for the user #1. In fact, the function contains the following code.

```
function user_access($string, $account = NULL) {
  global $user;

  if (!isset($account)) {
    $account = $user;
  }

  // User #1 has all privileges:
  if ($account->uid == 1) {
    return TRUE;
  } 

  // ...
}
```

Notice the control statement uses `$account->uid == 1`, not `$account->uid === '1'`.

Answer (score 4):

For a variable to be available in the scope of a function, it needs to have been initialised (or it needs to have been initialised in the global scope and imported into the local function using `global`).

At the moment there's nothing declaring or passing the `$vars` variable in...it hasn't been initialised, thus you get the warning.

You're passing a variable to the function called `$message`, which suggests your code should be:

```
$uid = $message->author->uid;
```

The confusion with `$vars/$variables` might be caused by the fact that it's sort of the standard name for the only argument passed to theme functions, e.g.

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_node(&$vars) {
  // Use $vars
```

Comment: Ok, I understand that I failed to declare it properly.  But are you saying the code, as written, should not work?  Because this has been working "correctly" on my site for a few months (which is to say, it at least checks the UID and does discard the message if 1 or 3).

Comment: Hmmm there must be something else going on then. Logically, the checks for `$uid !== '1'` and `$uid !== '3'` will never evaluate to `FALSE` as `$uid` is a `NULL` value, and therefore cannot equal 1 or 3

Comment: Hmm.  Well, I'm afraid to say I don't understand what's going on with the code exactly, but I do know that the module successfully discards UID 3 messages when enabled and UID 3 messages go through when the module is disabled.  I will add this to my list of things to look into one day.

Comment: Yeah that's definitely a strange one. It's always tricky to debug these sorts of things out of context, there might be something external to that function that's causing the anomaly (although I can't honestly think what that could be). As a sanity check you might try changing that line to `$uid = $message->author->uid;` on your dev site. If it still works, you've lost nothing and the code will at least be logically correct as well as functionally correct. If not then you know there's a bigger problem going on

Comment: @PatrickKenny User IDs are integers, while you are comparing them with a string, using `!==`. See my answer about that.

Comment: @kiamlaluno I was going to mention that, but as the $message is probably loaded by DBTNG it might be being attached to the object as a string, meaning the identity check passes. You're right of course though, it's not the best idea either way. Patrick - unless you're 100% sure the `uid` property is a string it would better to use the standard equality operator instead (`!=`)

Comment: He's assigning a NULL value to $uid and then saying `if $uid != 1`, which it's not, so the `if` statement runs. Whether he assigns NULL or 42, the `if` statement should run, no?

Comment: @CharlieS Yep that's right

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the type signature for that hook, it is

```
function hook_privatemsg_message_validate($message, $form = FALSE) {
}
```

`$vars` is not a function parameter, nor have you declared it as being a `gloabl`.  Using it as you have should make PHP complain (one of the various undefined variable notices).  As it stands, `$uid` would therefore be undefined when you try to extact something from `$vars`.

Comment: I see.  I didn't get a PHP error because this hook is evaluated based on a rule, so it never got printed out to the screen in dev.